# error: The method 'showSnackBar' can't be unconditionally invoked because the receiver can be 'null'

Tags: firebase, flutter

I am getting this error while executing a Firebase-based OTP verification interface. What should I do ?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please read [how to write a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). It is highly unlikely that anyone can help you if you don't provide details, what you tried, your code etc.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Verify that the text you are trying to display is not null.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).